# recursive import in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

in logging.py in my python library there are the lines:

```
import logging
```

and:

```
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL
```

I don't understand the meaning of importing logging within logging.py and 
also where (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL) are defined?

Comment: Logging in python is a module that helps you log information in as your program runs. Once logging is imported, you can use `DEBUG`, `INFO` etc... like this: `print "%s" % logging.DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

it's importing `logging` from python standard library, [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html),

also [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels) is log levels in that page (DEBUG, INFO, ...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone has messed up the imports a little bit? :)

In general, if you do

`import <module>`

You can refer to *all* its methods and objects as

`<module>.<method>`

Whereas if you do e.g,

`import <method1>, <constant1> from <module>`

You can refer to only the ones you explicitly mentioned as:

`<method1>`, `<constant1>` etc.

In this particular case I guess that the code author did not want to use module prefix for logging level constants.